# problem inserting json array into postgres: malformed error

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to insert an array of JSON values into a postgres database. But I'm getting this error:

```
error: malformed array literal: "{{"traits":{"belief":[],"personality":[],"physical":[]},"relationships":[]},{"traits":{"belief":[],"personality":[],"physical":[]},"relationships":[]}}"
```

If I'm correct, the array literal should take the form `"{{...},{...}}"`. As far as I know, this is the correct way to insert an array of JSON elements into a postgres table.

Here's my whole query if it helps:

```
INSERT INTO main(prev_snippets, next_snippets, req_characters, description, requirements, prereq_events, character_effects, world_effects, character_decisions)
        VALUES ('{"22","45","99"}', '{"33","22"}', '{{"traits":{"belief":[],"personality":[],"physical":[]},"relationships":[]},{"traits":{"belief":[],"personality":[],"physical":[]},"relationships":[]}}', 'cvdfgfg', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

`prev_snippets` and `next_snippets` are arrays of integers (I'll make those integers instead of strings when I get the JSON problem figured out), `req_characters` is a JSONB array, and `description` is text.

Please let me know how I can make my question better. Thanks a ton for the help.

Update:

Here's the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE main (
  id SERIAL NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY(id),
  prev_snippets INTEGER[],
  next_snippets INTEGER[],
  req_characters JSONB[],
  description TEXT NOT NULL,
  requirements JSONB[],
  prereq_events JSONB[],
  character_effects JSONB[],
  world_effects JSONB[],
  character_decisions JSONB[]
);
```

I believe I'm using postgres version 14.

Comment: What version of Postgres, please?

Comment: To your question add the table definition, in particular the actual declared types of the columns.

Comment: Are you 100% sure about all the array datatypes? It's usually a bad database design

Comment: @FrankHeikens Good point. Based on the suggestions here, I'm changing all my JSONB  array columns into just JSONB columns, since it's redundant. I might also switch to Mongo DB, as this is starting to look less like a relational database use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this with a Postgres `array` is :

```
insert into array_test 
 (jsonb_array) 
values 
(ARRAY['{"traits":{"belief":[],"personality":[],"physical":[]},"relationships":[]}'::jsonb, 
'{"traits":{"belief":[],"personality":[],"physical":[]},"relationships":[]}'::jsonb]);

select jsonb_array[1] from array_test ;
                                    jsonb_array                                     
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"traits": {"belief": [], "physical": [], "personality": []}, "relationships": []}
```

Though if it where me I would just use a `jsonb` field not a Postgres `array` of `jsonb` elements.

Answer (score 4):

You've mixed up JSONB with Postgres arrays.

`req_characters JSONB[]` is a Postgres array of JSONB values. This would be something like...

`array['{"traits":...}','{"traits":...}']`.

Embedding JSON in a Postgres array is unnecessarily complex. JSON already has arrays. In JSON, `{}` is a key/value object. `[]` is an array of elements.

Instead of using `jsonb[]` simply use `jsonb` and pass a JSON array.

`'[{"traits":...}, {"traits":...}]'`.

Most languages have built-in facilities to convert data to JSON. This is much simpler than embedding JSON in a Postgres Array. See [JSON.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html) for more.

---

For the same reason, I would suggest changing all the other arrays to simply be JSONB.

Also note that arrays and JSON are not a replacement for [join tables](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp). All of your arrays might be better done as join tables.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding your answer -- I'm trying to make an array of JSON elements. so the outer `{}` is to signify an array, and the second level of `{}` is to signify a JSON element.

Comment: @StLouis9 I just caught that you've declared it `jsonb[]` not `jsonb`. See my updated answer.