# String to Postgresql json array

Tags: postgresql

I have a text column with data that is being parsed to look like this:

```
{{"noteCode": "123", "noteText": "XYX"}}
{{"noteCode": "456", "noteText": "ABC"}, {"noteCode": "DE3", "noteText": "BG33"}}
```

The original text looks like this:

```
[{'noteCode': '123', 'noteText': 'XYX'}]
[{'noteCode': '456', 'noteText': 'ABC'}, {'noteCode': 'DE3', 'noteText': 'BG33'}]
```

I need to convert either one of these string formats into a valid Postgresql json[] column. I've tried a variety of things on both strings, but haven't been successful...

The original data conversion, source and language are beyond my control, as is the data type of the receiving column.  I'm starting with the original text above in a text column and ultimately, it needs to be converted to a json[] column.  Seemed trivial at first, but am stumped now.

Comment: I'd recommend making the column `jsonb`, not `json[]`. JSON already has arrays, you don't have to embed JSON into a Postgres Array. Most programming languages can turn data structures into JSON. And `jsonb` is generally superior to the `json` type.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [problem inserting json array into postgres: malformed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69560635/problem-inserting-json-array-into-postgres-malformed-error)

Comment: What programming language are you using to convert the data? Where is the data coming from?

Comment: @Schwern see my edits above... source and destination are beyond my control.

Comment: Sorry, the problem remains unclear. Perhaps if you showed us what you tried. Again, `json[]` is a bit of a nightmare, try to get that changed to `jsonb`.

Comment: @Schwern not sure what you're unclear about.  As you mentioned, json[] is the nightmare that I'm stuck with and I am unable to change it to jsonb.  Postgres is the database I'm stuck with (can't edit in C# or python) and re-insert and the text I have to start with is shown above.  Any help, other than change to jsonb, would be appreciated.

Comment: Let's see if we can make this clear. You have suspiciously JSON-like input `[{'noteCode': '123', 'noteText': 'XYX'}]` that you wish to insert into `json[]`. That much is clear. 1) What do you want to use to transform the data; entirely in Postgres? 2) You mention the data is "being parsed to look like this" `{{"noteCode": "123", "noteText": "XYX"}}`. What is its relevance to the question? It looks sort of like `json[]`; is this an attempt at parsing the original into `json[]`? If so, what is doing the parsing? 3) Please show us what you've tried, not just the result.

Comment: If it must be `json[]`, it might be simpler to use an external tool to transform the original text into JSON, and then have Postgres turn the JSON into `json[]`. Parsing an unknown format in Postgres is likely to make the problem more difficult than it has to be. Some sort of script is fetching the data and running the inserts, what language is that written in?